# Removing Step 2 "Shipping Information" from Magento Onepage Checkout

Tags: magento

I am currently using magento 1.5.1. I am also using a module to allow local store pickup. However, I want to remove the "Shipping Information" Step from the checkout process. I do not want to remove the "Shipping Method" part because it's required form my in store pickup module. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to remove the link to it in the file:
magento/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage.phtml

and then most likely edit 
magento/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/shipping.phtml or shipping-method/phtml

It might be a little difficult.
Let me know how this goes!